# find exclude directory

Tags: find

I am on Linux (Ubuntu) and I am would like to exclude certain directories (like .hg) when I am doing a

```
find | less
```

I tried the following to exclude the .hg directory from listing, but does not seem to work.

```
find -type d \( ! -iname \.hg \)
find -type d \( ! -name \.hg \)
find -type d \( ! -iname .hg \)
```

How do I exclude `.directory` in a find command

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the [research for a similar `find` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[find]+prune) I discovered the helpful explanation on [How to use '-prune' option of 'find' in sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1489405) by [Laurence Gonsalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90848/laurence-gonsalves).

You could use something like:

```
find . \( -type d -name .hg -prune \) -o \( -type f -name "foo" -print \)
```

or (without the name)

```
find . \( -type d -name .hg -prune \) -o \( -type f -print \)
```

The (escaped) parentheses `\(` and `\)` group the tests (`type` and `name`) and corresponding actions (`prune` and `print`, respectively) together left and right of the OR (`-o`).

Since `-o` has lower precedence than juxtaposition, you can omit the parentheses if you like. Many `find` implementations also let you skip the final `-print`.

```
find . -type d -name .hg -prune -o -type f -name "foo" -print
```

Comment: I was about to write my solution, but it appears to be exactly this. Personally I'd put the `-prune` inside the first set of brackets, and the `-type f -print` in a second set, just to make the and/or operations more obvious, but otherwise this looks spot-on to me.

Comment: I improved parentheses (and their reasoning) thanks to @me_and 's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `ack`: http://betterthangrep.com/

In addition to having a reasonable set of default excluded folders (.hg is a default exclude for instance), it is easy to exclude new folders:

```
ack --ignore-dir=.directory search_term
```

To bring this back to your use case where you are looking for a list of files, you would use the `-f` option, as in:

```
ack -f --ignore-dir=.directory
```

I switched from writing convoluted search/find commands to simple ack ones.

Tip: Put commonly used command line options (excluded folders for instance) into a .ackrc file.

Comment: Based on the `find | less` in the question, the OP is looking for a simple list of files. How does this help with that?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling As I stated in my answer, the -f option provides a list of files.

Answer (score -2):

you can try

```
find \( ! -regex '.*/\.directory\(\|/.*\)' \)
```

Comment: Pretty damn sure this does nothing like what the OP asked for.

Comment: I just thought this is what he mean by `.directory`