# Exclude directory in (native Solaris) find command

Tags: find, solaris

I'm trying to exclude the directory `/zones` in my `find` command. I don't have GNU find available, just the native Solaris `find`.

I tried something like this:

```
find / -type d ! -name zones
```

The problem is that with this exclude I also lose sub-directories like `/etc/zones`.

Is there a way to specify the complete directory name like:

```
find / -type d ! -name ^\/zones
```

I already tested lots of approaches but I can't include the `/` in front of the string.

Comment: does solaris find support asterisks? like `find / ! -name '*zones'` ?

Comment: maybe this [post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31252/find-exclude-directory) will help

Comment: Yes asteriks are supported but with an exclude on *zones I will end up with the same issue as before...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a portable way:

```
find / -type d -exec test {} = /zones \; -prune -o -type d -print
```

Note that GNU find might be available on an alternate directory depending on the Solaris release you are using (like `/usr/sfw/bin/gfind`, `/usr/gnu/bin/find`, ...).

Comment: This approach will probably work but search the /zones directory anyway which can result in very high execution times. It would be best to not search this directory in the first place.

Comment: @Nenzo I used `-prune` which is documented as `-prune Always yields true. Does not examine any directories or files in the directory structure below the pattern just matched.`

Comment: Thanks you're right I just tested your solution and it works just fine.

Comment: This worked just fine for me on Solaris 10. But I have a question: How do I skip multiple directories?

Comment: @dvai just insert extra `-o -exec test {} = /otherdir \; -prune` clauses before the last `-o -type d` one.