# find items only in a list of directories

Tags: find

If I have the following directories

```
a/ b/ c/d/ c/f/ g/
```

How can I  `find -name "something" -type f` in just `a/ c/f/` and `g/` without having to iterate through the list of directories I want and running `find` on it individually?

This is partially answered here: [find exclude directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31252/find-exclude-directory)

But I have 100s of directories to include and exclude so I was looking for a better solution where I could just specify a list of directories as an argument or a file with the directory names in them.

Thanks.

Comment: @StephenRauch I saw this but I have several directories to include / exclude. Writing a prune statement for each is tedious. I was looking for a simpler solution.

Comment: If it's too tedious to exclude each unwanted directory on the command line you need to provide some criterion that will allow a programmatic exclusion. There's nothing in the question that gives this so the question is currently unanswerable.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to include multiple directories to search you can just list them like:

```
find a/ c/f/ g/ -name "something" -type f
```