# ls all python files in a project, except for the files in migrations folders

Tags: bash, ls

I have a django project. I can list all of its python files with `ls **/**/**.py` How can I omit files that are in migrations folders?

Answer (score 0):

**`find`** command solution:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name "*.py" ! -path "*/migrations/*" ! -path "*/.*/*"
```

Comment: Not the same. `ls **/**/**.py` seems to be omitting hidden folders, and I need that

Comment: @Euphorbium, just to ignore hidden files? that's all?

Comment: Yes. Ignore the folders that start with a `.`

Comment: @Euphorbium, check my update

Comment: This runs like 100 times slower than ls.

Comment: @Euphorbium, looks like you'll never be satisfied. I feel like I should not have helped you at all ...

Comment: To exclude a directory, `-prune` should be used (like in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31269/70524), otherwise `find` still has to check every file in every `migrations` directory (and every hidden directory)

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type d -name 'migrations' -prune -o -type f -name '*.py'
```

This would first check the current pathname to see whether it is a directory, and if it is, if its name is `migrations`.  If that too is true, the directory is removed from the search list using `-prune`. It then goes on to look for files whose names end in `.py` and will output the pathnames of all of these.

This way, any `migrations` directories are not entered by `find`.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up simply excluding it with grep:

```
ls **/**/**.py | grep -v /migrations/
```

This works fast.

Comment: This only works if you first set the `globstar` shell option and if there's no `migrations` directory in the current directory (in which case `grep` would not remove it).  It also assumes there are no embedded newlines in filenames.

Comment: Also, with `globstar` set, it would be enough with `**.py` since `**` matches across `/`.